# How to create a fair multithreading double barrier?

Tags: multithreading, ipc, mutex, barrier, pthread-barriers

I have a double barrier multi-thread program working, but I don't know how to create a fair mechanism (using POSIX mutex, conditional variable barrier functions) - 
meaning: groups of threads will enter the first barrier by arrival time to barrier.

Pseodo code for the code I have till now (summarized, original code has more validations. Hope it's clear enough) -

1. mutex_lock;
2. ++_barrier->m_predicate;
3. /* block all threads ( except last at thread)  - 
     pending in barrier rendezvous point */

   if(_barrier->m_predicate != _barrier->m_barrierSize)
       {
           pthread_cond_wait(&_barrier->m_cond, &_barrier->m_mutex); 
       }
4. else
       {
           /* *Unblock all threads (by scheduling policy order) 
               that are currently blocked by cond parameter in Barrier 
              **Reset: Predicate value is "0" --> new batch of threads
                 enter 1st barrier */

   ```
       pthread_cond_broadcast (&_barrier->m_cond);
       ResetBarrier (_barrier);
   }
   ```

   /* end of critical code block */

   pthread_mutex_unlock(&_barrier->m_mutex);

Comment: To clarify - code is written in C

Comment: [The explanation why fair locks are an incredibly bad idea](http://joeduffyblog.com/2006/12/14/anticonvoy-locks-in-windows-server-2003-sp1-and-windows-vista/). And that's a fundamental issue even for the operating system itself. Trying to reimplement them in user code will be even worse.

Comment: OK - fair multi thread barrier (double barrier) was the instruction. OS is linux, not windows (relevant functions are POSIX, not system V).

Comment: Well if you're doing homework you should be doing it on your own. If it's not homework you should consider the problem and change your approach to not require a fair lock - that's generally th not too difficult

Comment: Any other answer?